# Is this jQuery code consistent across all versions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I've read somewhere that when you capture a jQuery object in a variable, say:

```
div = $("#someDiv");
```

A screenshot of that element is captured, so if you do something like this:

```
div2 = $("#someDiv"); // another handle
div2.css('background-color', 'rgb(12,75,54)');
```

and then do:

```
div.css('background-color'); // should NOT output "rgb(12, 75, 54)"
```

And yet, this is what happens, the `div` handle is aware of any changes that happen to the element. So I was thinking: maybe this behavior is introduced to a newer version of jQuery? Was this always true for all jQuery versions?

Comment: It always has been true. There is no "snapshot" at the moment in time, it is a reference to that element in the DOM.

Comment: note that some browsers may return `rgba`. The way they handle colors doesn't always match method you set them

Answer (score 0):

Even though `div = $("#someDiv");` creates a different *jQuery object* than `div2 = $("#someDiv");` the actual dom element within those jQuery objects is still the same

There can only be one of those and objects are passed as reference not by copying them.

Anything that happens within the dom node represented by `div` will be reflected in `div2`'s dom node....they are one and the same